# Sitecore 9 Form's field delete event

Tags: sitecore-forms

I need to do some customization on sitecore 9.0 form's field deletion. Any idea what i need to extend or override ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can add an event on trigger:form:Delete

```
<event name="trigger:form:Delete">
   <handler type="yourclass, yourdll" method="yourmethod" />
</event>
```

[image]